# Can Someone Help Me Remove This Error: Use of undeclared type 'bool'

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner with swift and I'm trying to complete my first app. While I was typing the code, it showed me this:

> Use of undeclared type 'bool'.

This is what I was trying to type:

```
override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: bool)
```

Comment: Hint: **All** *default* types in Swift start with a capital letter.

Comment: Really? I didn't know! I am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bool` is C boolean type. In swift you should use `Bool`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is not a default type. It should be `Bool`

Comment: Thank you this helped me, but sorry I only could put a check on one answer only. You both helped me.